# background service has stopped on miui rom

Tags: android, android-service

I am developing a background services and in OnDestroy Method, I've called an intent to start my services again. I'ts not started again on miui rom (Xiaomi mobile and huawei mobile).

How do I handle this?

```
public class NotificationsService extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    ApplicationLoader.postInitApplication();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public void onDestroy() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("example.app.start");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
}
```

In Manifest:

```
    <receiver android:name=".AppStartReceiver" android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="example.app.start" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Did you posted the broadcast receiver code ?

Comment: @W4R10CK not yet, because stackoverflow says: You can only post once every 90 minutes. :/

Comment: @W4R10CK http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41918691/sending-broadcast-to-restart-service-to-keep-alive-not-working-currectly

Comment: @AliKouroshfar Please have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56335831/5685911

Comment: This is very common problem in custom ROMs with different vendors as you have mentioned some. And solution is already available @Akki suggested already.

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473230/android-how-to-enable-autostart-option-programmatically-in-xiaomi-devices/65827056#65827056

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't new on Xiaomi because Xiaomi has a feature called app permission, where user has to allow the app to start automatically (Service).

Go like this and allow your app to autostart:

`Settings > permissions > Autostart`

Or,

Don't try to restart the same `Service` inside `onDestroy()` instead use `START_STICKY` inside `onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)` method.

Again you are sending broadcast not starting a service, Use `onDestroy` properly:

```
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
Intent intent = new Intent("example.app.start");
sendBroadcast(intent);
super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: It's true. It doesn't new on Xiaomi. But is there any way to keep-alive a service programatically without Mi Settings?

Comment: I am testing START_STICKY with OnDestroy, but not work and my service has stopped!

Comment: No, Its a memory term in MIUI that the user has to autostart the selected app and don't use `START_STICKY` inside `onDestroy` use inside `onStartCommand`

Comment: @AliKouroshfar you are sending broadcast not starting a service

Comment: It's true. i'm sending broadcast. but i have a receiver that received my broadcast and start my service

        <receiver android:name=".AppStartReceiver" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="example.app.start" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: post that broadcast question separately with code. This question you posted is about service

Comment: Give it a try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49473230/android-how-to-enable-autostart-option-programmatically-in-xiaomi-devices/65827056#65827056