# Sending broadcast to restart service to keep-alive not working correctly

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcastreceiver

I have an Android service that in onDestroy() method I'm sending a broadcast to restart my service.
It's work on sony and samsung rom! but not work in Xiaomi or Huawei rom.

How do I handle this?

This is my code.

Manifest:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".Receiver.AppStartReceiver"
        android:enabled="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="example.app.start" />
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" /> 
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Service:

```
public class NotificationsService extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    ApplicationLoader.postInitApplication();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

public void onDestroy() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("example.app.start");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}}
```

Receiver:

```
public class AppStartReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    AndroidUtilities.runOnUIThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            ApplicationLoader.startPushService();
        }
    });
}}
```

ApplicationLoader.startPushService():

```
    public static void startPushService() {

    applicationContext.startService(new Intent(applicationContext, NotificationsService.class));}
```

Comment: This isn't going to work globally, ever.  YOu're in a low resource condition if its killing your service.  If you get restarted, you'd just be killed again immediately.  They're skipping the whole process.  You're doing the right thing by returning START_STICKY, when they have enough resources to keep you running you'll be restarted.

Comment: Why don't you register your receiver in activity ?

Comment: I dont understand why do you need broadcast to restart the service. You are returning START_STICKY which will  restart the service again.

Comment: @W4R10CK Because i registered it in manifest. Why should register receiver in activity?

Comment: what is androidutilities ?

Comment: @AjayShrestha Always not working START_STICKY. I need a service that always run.

Comment: @W4R10CK This is a class that prepare some utilities for me like showToast, showKeyboard, compare and other. in runOnUIThread, i called another class that name is ApplicationLoader that have object of Handler and use it to "post" my runnable.

Comment: @W4R10CK     public static void runOnUIThread(Runnable runnable, long delay) {
        if (delay == 0) {
            ApplicationLoader.applicationHandler.post(runnable);
        } else {
            ApplicationLoader.applicationHandler.postDelayed(runnable, delay);
        }
    }

Comment: use `ApplicationLoader.startPushService();` only don't use anything esle

Comment: @AliKouroshfar If that doesnt work why dont you use Binder .Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15758980/android-service-needs-to-run-always-never-pause-or-stop